# Provide CPU time and memory to subprocess

Tags: python, c++, docker, subprocess, resources

I have been researching over on how to provide Python `subprocess` it's own `time` and `memory`.

```py
import resource
import subprocess


def set_memory_time(seconds):
    limit_virtual_memory(seconds)
    usage_start = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
    print("usage_start ", usage_start)
    try:
        p = subprocess.check_output(
            ['docker exec -it cpp_compiler sh -c "g++ -o Test1 prog1.cpp && ./Test1 < input.txt"'],
            shell=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    usage_end = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
    print("usage_end ", usage_end)
    cpu_time = usage_end.ru_utime - usage_start.ru_utime
    print("cpu_time ", cpu_time)


def limit_virtual_memory(seconds):
    max_virtual_memory = 10 * 1024 * 1024  # 10 MB
    usage_start = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (max_virtual_memory, resource.RLIM_INFINITY))
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_CPU, (seconds, usage_start.ru_utime + seconds))
```

Problem is that `resource.setrlimit` set limit for the main process and subprocess uses that limit. When limit exceeds it actually kills process as well.

1. Overall goal that I am trying to achieve here is `subprocess.check_output(['docker exec -it cpp_compiler sh -c "g++ -o Test1 prog1.cpp && ./Test1 < input.txt"']` this line should not more resource than allocated. 
   *Is there way to achieve this in python ?*
2. The problem I am trying to solve here is trying to allocate `CPU time` and `memory` limit for user submitted `CPP` code. `CPP` code will eventually run on docker container for sandboxing purpose, but want to have limit on the resource it uses.

It would be really helpful if someone can provide input on the problem and potential solution or correction in above code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't limit the resource utilization of an arbitrary `docker exec` process.

Docker uses a client/server model, so when you run `docker exec` it's just making a request to the Docker daemon.  When you try to to `setrlimit` to limit the subprocess's memory, it only limits the `docker exec` process itself; but that makes a request to the Docker daemon, which in turn launches a new process in the container namespace.  None of these processes are children of each other, and none of them beyond the original `docker exec` inherit these resource limits.

If instead you launch a new container, you can use [Docker's resource limits](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) on the new container.  These don't limit the absolute amount of CPU time, but you probably want to limit the runtime of the launched process in any case.

You should generally avoid using the `subprocess` module to invoke `docker` commands.  Constructing shell commands and consuming their output can be tricky, and if your code isn't perfect, it's very easy to use a shell-injection attack to use the `docker` command to root the host.  Use something like the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead.

So, if you wanted to launch a new container, with a fixed memory limit, and to limit its execution time, you could do that with something like:

```py
import docker
import requests
client = docker.from_env()

container = client.containers.run(
  image='some/image:tag',
  command=['the', 'command', 'to', 'run'],
  detach=True,
  mem_limit=10485760 # 10 MiB
)
try:
  container.wait(timeout=30) # seconds
except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
  # container ran over its time allocation
  container.kill()
  container.wait()
print(container.logs())
container.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks @David Maze , thats nice explanation. Actually, restrictions on container won't work in our case, as we want to run multiple test cases simultaneously in a container and want to restrict the time/memory limit on each test case in a container, but not on container. So, do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Containers aren't particularly expensive and don't have hard resource isolation; if you run four processes in four containers, their performance should be comparable to running them in a single container, and the setup will be much simpler.  I'd run one container per process here.